# SRP hash rule that cause interaction with Windows File Explorer

Tags: windows, security, group-policy, windows-10

I'm currently implementing Software Restriction Policy rules. While I was doing that, I noticed that I couldn't do a right click on directories in the Windows file explorer and selecting "Properties". I don't get the properties windows. Windows just does nothing. I found that this bug reproduced on my two computers that were configured with this GPO. I don't know if this problem hide something more disturbing.

I disabled the GPO that implement SRP. The bug stopped to occurs.  This confirmed that was something from my SRP policy that cause this problem.

I created my policy from scratch again, step by step to find what rule caused the issue. After many gpupdate and reboots, I found that the problem was caused by a single hash rule.

This is the rule in question:
[image: Screenshot]

The default policy is to deny everything and allow only whitelisted entries (paths and hashes). The hashed DLL come with CrashPlan PROe. Crashplan put this DLL in %APPDATA%\Local\Temp\.cpswt. You can find the DLL [here](https://framadrop.org/r/Ve7hW_U_u2#pUE315ChB0WtROgVByTxQmESHyzEroPQ5OksTyNCl%20U=).

I have others hash rules that are not causing any issues.

Is there any known bugs about hash rules that interact with Windows File Explorer? Any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue but far worse. My windows explorer basically fail / stalls half way while logging in.

This happens if I add a rule to UNRESTRICT a hash of an particular exe (Using Computer or User Software restriction policy) The problem is only in Windows 10, Windows 7 is just fine always has been.

If I login it stays at the login screen for a couple of minutes, eventually it gets to an all black desktop that has the taskbar nothing else. The cursor is on the circle of death and can't click anywhere. (all I can do is ctrl-alt-delete, logout)

I've stopped using SRP hashing rules in Windows 10. I'm presuming Microsoft is no longer supporting SRP in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 introduced AppLocker, you should not use SRP on Windows 7 and above:
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh994614

Comment: AppLocker requires Windows Enterprise. This doesn't work with Windows Pro.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't mean that you should continue using SRP.If you are using Windows Pro, you should probably consider using a third party product but not the legacy SRP.